# PostgreSQL Row Security Policies is not working for CREATE POLICY FOR UPDATE WITH CHECK (false);

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

I'm trying to set up row level security on some tables. By now I had no issues with `INSERT` and `SELECT`, now trying to handle `UPDATE`.

I tried many things but really got stuck when I defined the policy with `WITH CHECK (false)` and I have the ability to execute updates on that table with rls user despite the policy defined.

Why is that happening? I expected all updates on that table to fail because `WITH CHECK` is a boolean validator.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
                "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                "name" varchar (50) NOT NULL
               );
```

```
create role rls_user NOINHERIT;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO rls_user;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO rls_user;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO rls_user;

alter table t enable row level security;

CREATE POLICY t_update ON t
FOR UPDATE WITH CHECK (false);

----> CREATE POLICY t_update ON t
----> FOR UPDATE USING (false); ---> also doesn't work
```

```
set role rls_user;

UPDATE t 
SET name = 'blabla'
WHERE "id" = 1;

---> expected: UPDATE FAILED

---> result: 
--->           UPDATE 0

--->           Query returned successfully in 73 msec.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your policy makes the table appear empty for the `rls_user`, because it has no `USING` clause.

Therefore, the `UPDATE` will never modify a row (`UPDATE 0`), and since no row is modified, no row has to pass the `CHECK` condition and no error is thrown.

Note that you granted the user `UPDATE` permissions on the table, so it is allowed to run all updates on the table, as long as the modified rows pass the `CHECK` condition.

Comment: Thanks! when I saw the `Query returned successfully` I thought the policy doesn't work, I expected an error.I didn't notice the zero in  `UPDATE 0`.